# SQL Query with Case Statement

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to check if the customer has a specific product. If they do, return yes.  If they do not, return no.

So, I wrote a query that returns that. However, I do not want to type in `ProductFamily` name. I would like to interjoin.

```
SELECT 
    ID,
    (CASE 
        WHEN ProductFamily IN ('Product')
           THEN 'Yes'
           ELSE 'No' 
     END) AS 'O'
FROM
    [source].[Opportunity] A
```

The following query lets me know if the `ProductFamily` mapping:

```
SELECT *
FROM [reference].[ProductFamilyMapping]
WHERE (isA = 1)
ORDER BY productfamilyname
```

How do you inter join a Case statement?

Comment: Can you edit the post and add some sample input entries as well as your desired output format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a subquery in the IN statement rather than hardcoded text, although you will need to specify the column name (i.e. "SELECT mycolumn" rather than "SELECT *").

```
SELECT 
    ID
    ,(CASE 
        WHEN  ProductFamily IN 
        (SELECT ProductFamily FROM [reference].[ProductFamilyMapping] where (isA = 1))
          THEN 'Yes'
        ELSE 'No' END) as 'O'
From  [source].[Opportunity] A
```

(I am assuming the column name in [reference].[ProductFamilyMapping] is also ProductFamily).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative could be using CTE and LEFT JOIN.
Try this:

```
WITH PFM AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT ProductFamily FROM [reference].[ProductFamilyMapping] where (isA = 1)
)
SELECT 
    ID
    ,CASE WHEN PFM.ProductFamily IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS 'O'
From  [source].[Opportunity] A 
LEFT JOIN PFM ON A.ProductFamily = PFM.ProductFamily
```